# undefined variable data when passing data variable to view page from controller in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel 5.4 undefined variable data 
passing data as variable controller to view getting undefined variable error how to fixed it.

```
 public function getdata()
    {
        $data['data'] = DB::table('location')->get();
            if(count($data) > 0) 
            {
                return view('admin.location',compact('data'));
            }
            else
            {
                return view('admin.location');
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are getting error in view or in Controller???

Comment: its okay problem fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

1. First Set $data variable as null so undefined variable error is gone
2. Check $data is not null then print results

```
 
    public function getdata()
    {
        $data = null;
        $data = DB::table('location')->get();
        if(!$data->isEmpty()) 
        {
            return view('admin.location',compact('data'));
        }else{
            return view('admin.location’,compact('data'));
        }
    }
```